# Correct domain model variable lowerUpperCase

Tags: caching, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I created an domain model with an attribute "external_url" in TCA. But in the Domain Model I wrote "externalURL" instead of "externalUrl". Now I want to correct this. But allways when I change this I got an Exception "#1251315967: Could not determine the child object type."

I cleared allready the Cache within the install tool (typo3 cache and opcode cache) and cleared all `cf_*` tables in the Database. I also deleted manually the `typo3temp/Cache/` directory. But the error doesn't disappear.

What must I do that this renaming get effect!? In my development enviroment it works instantly...

**Edit:** More information:

My annotation in the domain model:

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $externalUrl = '';
```

My TCA:

```
  'external_url'           => array(
    'exclude' => 0,
    'label'   => 'LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_model.external_url',
    'config'  => array(
      'type' => 'input',
      'max' => 1024,
      'size' => 50,
      'softref' => 'typolink',
      'eval' => 'trim',
      'wizards' => array(
        'link' => array(
          'icon' => 'link_popup.gif',
          'JSopenParams' => 'height=300,width=500,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1',
          'module' => array(
            'name' => 'wizard_element_browser',
            'urlParameters' => array(
              'mode' => 'wizard'
            )
          ),
          'title' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:header_link_formlabel',
          'type' => 'popup'
        ),
        '_PADDING' => 2
      )
    )
  ),
```

and if needed the sql column definition:

```
external_url varchar(1024) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
```

Comment: I tried to rename the field to externalUri (external_uri), but the same exception occurs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you deactivated/activated the extension? 
have you cleared `/typo3temp/autoload/` ?

some information is stored outside the caches, which are cleared with the build in buttons.

also missing dependencies may be involved where the loading order is important (and the last activated extension is loaded last). Be sure to have clean dependencies!

Comment: deactivated/activated helped. The extension has no depencies. Autoload directory doesn't exist.

Comment: For the record, next time you can use the install tool to "clear all caches". If that operation helped it is because of the reflection cache which will clear when you use the install tool. Much easier if other extensions depend on the one you want to reload.

Comment: @ClausDue: I have used the "clear all caches" serveral times.

Comment: Unless you do it through the install tool this won't clear system caches. To gain access to explicitly clearing the system cache your site must be in Development context (via SetEnv in Apache). The install tool cache clearing will always clear this cache regardless of Development context.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a typo or similar error in one or more 1) property names or 2) missing/incorrect `@var` annotations in your model. The error comes when the Reflection framework is unable to determine the type of a specific property by analysing the annotation it has.

Comment: My annotations looks correct. I have updated my question with additional Code.

Comment: Scan your project for any and all references to the old name, including in Fluid templates. Make sure you don't POST or otherwise send the property name to a plugin action using the wrong name. Use the install tool to clear the system caches (which is where the reflection cache lives). Aside from that we would need a *lot* more information to be able to find your problem and I'm almost certain you will find the cause in one or more of my suggestions above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you any data which might reference the old attribute?
are the database tables valid?

Comment: I don't find any occurs of the old name. The attribute was only used in fluid  in the same extension and were also renamed. The database table is working. All other fields of the model are accessable and working correctly.

Comment: Have you deactivated/activated the extension? have you cleared /typo3temp/autoload/ ?

Comment: de- and activate the extension solves the problem... Do you have an explaination why? I have cleared the cache several times. Cleared many "cf_"-Tables several times and searched the whole project for the occur of the old attribute an dont find anything.

Comment: Maybe you would give the hint with deactivate/activate as answer so i can mark it.